# buildah: use different directory than /tmp for temporary files

Tags: linux, docker, tmp

My `/tmp` directory is too small which results in an error when I try to commit an image via `buildah`:

```
$ buildah commit $container foo:bar
...
error storing layer "42" to file: write /tmp/buildah317710758/layer: no space left on device
ERRO[0008] exit status 1
```

How can I tell `buildah` to use a different directory for temporary files? I tried with the following environment variables

```
TMP=/mytmp
TMPDIR=/mytmp
TEMP=/mytmp
```

without luck.

Comment: Does putting an `export` in front the declaration change anything, e.g., `export TMPDIR=/mytmp`?

Comment: sadly no, this doesn't change anything

Comment: @MaxMaier: Setting TMPDIR definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

Just define TMPDIR like the example below:

```
$ export TMPDIR="${HOME}/tmp/buildah"
$ mkdir -p "${TMPDIR}"
```